# Row class is not being divided into all the 12 columns of screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light pip-footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        HP 90/90
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        LEVEL 1
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        AP 50/50
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I am declaring the class container, and right after that I am delcaring the class row, but the row is not completely being distributed on whole screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have wrapped the `.row` and `.col-*` classes into `<nav></nav>` tag.

If you are intended to create Nav, follow this link - [Bootstrap Nav](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navs/)

I have included some styiling just to change the background of columns for better visibility.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
    .col-lg-3 {
        background-color: aqua;
    }

    .col-lg-6 {
        background-color: blueviolet;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            HP 90/90
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            LEVEL 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            AP 50/50
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```